# Can/How to use project configuration keys as job parameters in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I'm using the API to add some project configuration keys and would like to use them as job parameters. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it? I've looked in the official documentation but am not seeing much.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that is achievable, from the [documentation](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/configuration-file-reference.html#project-global-execution-variables), you will need to update the project’s configuration with a “Project global execution variable” key and value, then that variable will be available in all execution contexts as ${globals.X} and can be referenced in scripts and commands. You can send the project’s configuration key as JSON, xml or plain text via curl or as a file directly via the [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/).  e.g:

If you use the “rd” cli, you need to create a file, which can be a .properties, JSON or YAML file. We will create a JSON file named test.json, that contains the following ‘KEY’ and ‘VALUE’:

```
{ "project.globals.test" : "testvalue" }
```

Then, you can update the project configuration with this rd command syntax:

```
rd projects configure update -f [/path/to/test.json] -p [project_name]
```

That will update your projects configuration. Then you can reference it as follows:

```
Via bash: $RD_GLOBALS_TEST
Via command: ${globals.test}
In a script content: @globals.test@
```

Alternatively, you could use the API directly with curl. For this example I’m using an API token to authenticate with Rundeck’s API and sending the same key and value, but as xml:

```
curl -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: INSERT_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d '<property key="project.globals.test" value="valuetest"/>' -X PUT http://[RD_HOST]:[PORT]/api/23/project/[PROJECT_NAME]/config/[KEY]
```

Hope it helps.